# Trigger on count of items

Tags: javascript, meteor

Is there any way I can trigger an event when the number of items exceeds a limit in a collection? I need to periodically clear out test data for a public facing demo (I suppose I could do it on a timer, but it may need to be cleared faster).

I considered using an `observeChanges` but I feel that would involve a lot of overhead doing the count each time. Would setting up a dep trigger of some kind work? Or is there a sneakier solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polling with a timer seems like the obvious solution, but if you want to be more precise you could try something like [meteor-collection-hooks](https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks) and use the [before.insert](https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks#beforeinsertuserid-doc) callback.